# Function filler is not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to try the below code but maybe the timing is wrong

```js
 var nhanvien = [
    {
        id1: 001,
        id2: 002,
        id3: 004,
        sanluong: 200,
        "Start": "5:35:00",
    },
    {
        id1: 003,
        id2: 002,
        sanluong: 200,
        "Start": "8:35:00",
        "Start2": "17:16:00",
    }, 
    {
        id1: 004,
        id2: 001,
        sanluong: 500,
        "Start": "8:35:00",
        "Start2": "17:16:00",
        "Start3": "17:16:00",
    }
 ]
```

```js
var a = nhanvien.filter(function(o) {
    if (o.id1 == 001 || o.id2 == 001 || o.id3 == 001)
        if (o.Start < "6:00:00") return o
})
```

I just need any object have id = 001 ( id1 or id2 or id3  have value = 001)
and start before 5:00:00 AM
but it's just right when condition is start, properti start2 is wrong

Specifically, when you run this code, the object return value start2 is bigger than "6:00:00"

```js
var a = nhanvien.filter(function(o) {
    if (o.id1 == 001 || o.id2 == 001 || o.id3 == 001)
        if (o.Start2 < "6:00:00") return o
})
```

Initially, i used function fillter of lodash then i used function like this code

Comment: In your condition `o.Start < "6:00:00"`, you are comparing `string` and if you wish your condition to work then you need to add padding of `0` when your `hour` value is between `1-9`. So it should be `o.Start < "06:00:00"`. Also you need to modify your `Start`, `Start2`, `Start3` values as well and pad `0` wherever needed. For string comparison you can refer  https://javascript.info/comparison#string-comparison

Comment: Numeric literals starting with a zero are considered to be octal numbers. In your example this will not matter, but a literal `014` would be evaluated as decimal `12`.

Answer (score 0):

So, let's elaborate the function that you are using:

```
var a = nhanvien.filter(function (o) {
   if (o.id1 == 001 || o.id2 == 001 || o.id3 == 001)
      if(o.Start < "6:00:00")
        return o;
})
```

The issues are following:

1. Only returning for one condition. You need to return booleanish value for filtering. So, you can try following:

```
nhanvien.filter(function (o) {
   return (o.id1 == 001 || o.id2 == 001 || o.id3 == 001) && o.Start < "06:00:00"
})
```

2. You can't compare duration using string like that. E.g.-

```
"17:16:00" > "8:35:00" // returns false
```

But in your case it should be true. So, you can append zeros.

```
17:16:00" > "08:35:00" // returns true
```

Also, for your note, 001 and 1 is same in js unless you convert to string.

Comment: but if i run condition with start,it's right, but, start 2 and start3 => why? –

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are comparing durations using string.

For better handling time string comparison. You can write a function to convert a given time string into seconds:

```js
const toSeconds = timeString => {
  const bits = timeString.split(':');
  return bits[0] * 3600 + bits[1] * 60 + bits[2] * 1;
};
```

And then modify the filter logic like this:

```js
const results = nhanvien.filter(function (o) {
  if (o.id1 === '001' || o.id2 === '001' || o.id3 === '001') {
    if (toSeconds(o.Start) < toSeconds('06:00:00')) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
});
```

Comment: so weird@@ but if i run condition with  start,it's right, but, start 2 and start3 => why?

Answer (score 0):

Refer [string-comparison](https://javascript.info/comparison#string-comparison) to know how `<` & `>` works with `string`. Instead of comparing the `string`, I would prefer to convert your time value to `seconds` and then compare.

```js
var nhanvien = [{
  id1: 001,
  id2: 002,
  id3: 004,
  sanluong: 200,
  "Start": "5:35:00",
}, {
  id1: 003,
  id2: 002,
  sanluong: 200,
  "Start": "8:35:00",
  "Start2": "17:16:00",
}, {
  id1: 004,
  id2: 001,
  sanluong: 500,
  "Start": "8:35:00",
  "Start2": "17:16:00",
  "Start3": "17:16:00",
}];

// get seconds from time string
function getSeconds(str) {
  // split time string with : and convert values to integer
  let parts = str.split(':').map(i => parseInt(i));
  // multiply hour with 3600, minutes with 60 & add them with seconds
  return parts[0] * 3600 + parts[1] * 60 + parts[2];
}

// compare two string
function compareTime(time1, time2) {
  // check if we have values in time1 & time2 variables
  // if both variables having values then check both are having valid time value, ie. it has hour, minute & seconds separated by :
  // compare both times by converting them to seconds
  return time1 && time2 && time1.split(':').length == 3 && time2.split(':').length == 3 && getSeconds(time1) < getSeconds(time2);
}

// use arrow function in filter and we need to return boolean expression
let a = nhanvien.filter(o => (o.id1 == 001 || o.id2 == 001 || o.id3 == 001) && compareTime(o.Start, "6:00:00"));
let b = nhanvien.filter(o => (o.id1 == 001 || o.id2 == 001 || o.id3 == 001) && compareTime(o.Start2, "6:00:00"));
// for test and to return some value updated start time to 20:00:00 i.e. 8 PM.
let c = nhanvien.filter(o => (o.id1 == 001 || o.id2 == 001 || o.id3 == 001) && compareTime(o.Start2, "20:00:00"));

console.log("a", a);
console.log("b", b);
console.log("c", c);
```

Comment: why is there such a difference@@???? Is 6:00:00 different from 18:00:00 ? 6:00:00 is morning time, and 18:00:00 is 6:00:00 is evening time right?

Comment: Star and Star2 is same, but why diffirent???

Comment: That is just for testing. You can set whatever time you want to set. I just set `18:00:00`, so that filter can return at least one result.

Comment: i tried run start2 < 6:00:00 is not result@@, but start still run

Comment: Check updated answer. You might want like this `let b = nhanvien.filter(o => (o.id1 == 001 || o.id2 == 001 || o.id3 == 001) && compareTime(o.Start2, "6:00:00"));`

Comment: yes, because i must analysis data following 3 step
step 1:    time( start1, start2, start3) < "6:00:00"
step2: 6:00:00<= ( start1, start2, start3) < 17:00:00
step3: ( start1, start2, start3) >= 17:00:00

Comment: do you have a quick way to do all 3 steps below?